# Logarithm of the determinant of a positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, trace, positive-definite

For positive definite $C=LL^T$, where $L$ is the lower triangular Cholesky factor of $C$, why is $\log(\det(C))=2\operatorname{trace}(\log(L))$? I know that if $\{\lambda_i\}$ are the eigenvalues of $C$, $\det(C)=\prod_i\lambda_i$, so that $\log(\det(C))=\sum\log(\lambda_i)$ but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: By $|C|$, do you mean $|\det C|\,$? $\qquad$

Comment: As written, the left side of your desired conclusion is log of a matrix. Did you mean log(det(C))?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question. I meant for $|C|$ to indicate $\det(C)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint 1: $\det(C)=\det(LL^T)=\det(L)\det(L^T)=\det(L)^2$, so $\log\det(C)=2\log\det(L)$. Denote by $\lambda_i$ the eigenvalues of $L$ and continue in the same way as you tried.

Hint 2: For the Jordan normal form $L=SJS^{-1}$ it holds
$\log(L)=S\log(J)S^{-1}$, so 
$$
\operatorname{trace}\log(L)=\operatorname{trace}(S\log(J)S^{-1})=\operatorname{trace}\log(J).
$$

Comment: It seems like if I'm using your hint I don't need to reference eigenvalues. Relying on the fact that the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of its diagonal elements
$\log(\det(C))=\log(\det(LL^T))=\log(\det(L)^2)=2\log\prod_i L_{ii}=2\sum_i\log(L_{ii})$

Comment: @JimSlonder Right. If $L$ is a Cholesky factor (lower triangular), then the thing is becoming easier.